# How can I delete an element from an array using its index?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Trying to delete from this array:

```
array = ["Dog", "Cat", "John Cena"]
```

But those won't work:

```
array.delete(1)
array.delete([1])
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "those won't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Also, another hint: it would be very helpful if you could explain what, *precisely* is unclear to you about the documentation of `Array#delete`. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't stumble over the same problems you did. Make the world a better place!

Answer (score 5):

It's [`delete_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) you needed:

```
array = ["Dog", "Cat", "John Cena"]
#=> ["Dog", "Cat", "John Cena"]
array.delete_at(1)
#=> "Cat"
array
#=> ["Dog", "John Cena"]
```

Please check the [doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/) more often, you'll probably find the thing you needed most of the times.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
array = ["Dog", "Cat", "John Cena"]
array[1, 1] = []
array # => ["Dog", "John Cena"]
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated before you should be using Ruby Docs for help like this Ruby has amazing documentation and is a shame to waste the wealth of knowledge here.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at

[image]